# How can I loop a question until the list is complete

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

enter code hereHow can I loop a question to fill up a list? I need user to input five numbers. Everytime user inputs a number I append the number into a list. My problem is, the code doesn't loop, so it only takes one input from user and the code stops.

here's the extract of my code:

```
    def funct1():
        for i in range(5):
            user = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
            userList.append(user)
            return userList
        
    userList = []   
    Sum_Num()
    print(userList)
```

I tried doing

for l in range(5) and while True but none worked.

Comment: what about `while len(my_list) <5:` or somthing ?

Comment: Both `for i in range(5)` and `while True` should work if done right. How are you trying to use them? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @John Coleman hello, i edited my question to show my code

Comment: The problem with your code is that the `return` was within the body of the loop. Thus you return after the first iteration. You need to unindent that line one level so that it is after the loop. Also -- if you define a function then you should use it. That function won't run itself and somehow populate variables which occur elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def funct1():
    userList = []
    while len(userList) < 5:  # Keep looping until the list has 5 numbers
        user = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
        userList.append(user)

    return userList

userList = funct1()
print(userList)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should really provide a minimally reproducible code example, but I would assume you are having an indent error. This snippet should be what you are looking for:

```
values = []
for i in range(5):
    values.append(input())
print(values)
```

Edit: After you posted your relevant code, I can see that you do have an indent error. The return statement needs to exist outside of the for loop.

```
    def funct1():
        for i in range(5):
            user = int(input('Enter a Number: '))
            userList.append(user)
        return userList
        
    userList = funct1()   
    print(userList)
```